# Ultralimit of metric spaces vs. inductive limits of underlying topological spaces

Tags: ct.category-theory, mg.metric-geometry, limits-and-colimits, ultrafilters

Let $\{(X_n,d_n)\}_{n =1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of bounded metric spaces such that:

- $X_n \subseteq X_{n+1}$ is a metric subspace of $X_n$.

Let $\omega$ denote a non-principal ultrafilter (i.e.: complements of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are always in $\omega$) and let $X_{\omega}$ denote the corresponding [ultralimit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralimit) metric space.

Let $F:\mathit{Met} \rightarrow \mathit{Top}$ be the forgetful functor.  Then the inclusions of $F(X_n)$ into $F(X_{n+1})$ are continuous and thus $(F(X_n),(\mathbb{N},\leq))$ form an inductive system; hence, we can take the inductive limit in $\mathit{Top}$.  Denote this inductive limit by $\varinjlim F(X_n)$.

How are $X_{\omega}$ and $\varinjlim F(X_n)$ related?  I expect that $\varinjlim F(X_n)$ can be identified with a dense subset of $X_{\omega}$ but maybe I'm mistaken...

Comment: You get an isometric embedding. Its image is not always dense. For instance if each $X_n$ is a set of $n$ points pairwise at distance one: both are discrete spaces, so the embedding is closed, and not an equality since the union is countable while the ultralimit isn't.

Comment: @YCor your comments is a complete answer --- why not to make an anwer from it (so the question will not show up in unanswered).

Comment: There is no need to use $F$ --- you can define direct limit in the category of metric spaces.